# Am I handling this route.params properly when using a nested navigator?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation-v5, routeparams

In my app, I have a modal that is supposed to pop up if the app detects the user came from the "FinishingScreen" other than that, the modal should not pop up.

I have a " Drawer Tab Navigator " nested inside of my " Main Tab Navigator "

When I navigate from the FinishingScreen to my HomeScreen, the modal pops up because didComeFromFinishingScreen == true

When I navigate to any of the screens contained in the Drawer, then back to the HomeScreen, the modal pops up again because didComeFromFinishingScreen is still returning true.

I believe this has to do with how I am handling the route.params.

Below is the code that I use to handle the route.params:

Code inside of FinishingScreen making modal initially toggle

```
const checkConfirm = async () => {
  return await client_instance.stop_running().then(
   ()=>navigation.navigate('Home', {
      didComeFromFinishingScreen: true, 
     })
    )
   }
  

 ...
  <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={checkConfirm}   
 >
   <Text>Stop Running</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Checking if didComeFromFinishingScreen == true inside the HomeScreen

```
if(route.params?.didComeFromFinishingScreen){
     if(isFocused){
              setModalVisible(true) 
     }
}

   return()=>{
           console.log('cleanup function is closing modal')
              if(isFocused){
            setModalVisible(false)
         }
  }
```

Going from the HomeScreen to one of the screens inside the Drawer

```
<DrawerItem
    icon={({color, size }) => (
    <Icon 
        name="account-outline"
        color={color}
        size={height*0.032}
    />
    )}
    label= {i18n.t('prof')}
    onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('ProfileStackScreen',
        {didComeFromFinishingScreen: false}
        )}}
/>
```

Navigating back to the HomeScreen from any of the screens in the Drawer

```
<DrawerItem
    icon={({color, size }) => (
        <Icon 
        name="home-outline"
        color={color}
        size={height*0.032}
    />
    )}
    label= {i18n.t('home')}
    onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('HomeDrawer', {
    didComeFromFinishingScreen: false})
    }}
/>
```